# iOS presentViewController animating when turned off

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, presentviewcontroller

I am having a bit of an issue here. When I click my track button in my main view I have the button taking me to a new view were it displays tracking information. One problem I am having is that when its moving to the new view any labels are starting small and animating to turn to the normal size. I'm not sure if I have explained it properly but the view is animating when I have it set not to. I will attach code below.

Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)ordertrack {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"track1"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

UPDATE:

I still have not got any of the solutions to work, I have attached the gif below to show the problem you will see the back button will resize.

https://imgflip.com/gif/wwqq7

EDITED:

Adding code for Track1.m

```
    //
    //  Track1.m
    //  uDropOff 3
    //
    //  Created by Curtis Boylan on 06/01/2016.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Curtis Boylan. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "Track1.h"

    @interface Track1 ()

    @end

    @implementation Track1

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    - (IBAction)back {
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
   @end
```

Comment: Where is your animation code.. Is it in current view controller.. or in new view controller?

Comment: I don't have any animation code.

Comment: I still have not got any of the solutions to work, I have attached the gif below to show the problem you will see the back button will resize.

https://imgflip.com/gif/wwqq7

Answer (score 2):

@ChikabuZ speaks truth. (voted)

The `animated` parameter on `presentViewController:animated:completion:` controls whether the new view controller slides onto the screen or simply appears. It has no effect on what the new view controller does once it appears.

If the new "track1" view controller has animations in it's setup code, those will still occur. You'll need to build your own mechanism to tell it not to animate. (Perhaps add a `dontAnimateInitialDisplay` property to the `track1` VC, and write your code so if `dontAnimateInitialDisplay` is true, the animations are skipped. Then you'd change your code above like this:

```
- (IBAction)ordertrack {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //Cast "vc" to the correct type so we have access to the 
    //dontAnimateInitialDisplay property
    Track1VC *vc = (Track1VC *)
      [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"track1"];
    vc.dontAnimateInitialDisplay = TRUE;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your autolayout constraints are being updated to reflect their contents. Are you changing the contents of any of your views during `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` ?

Comment: I have tried Duncans exact code and I am getting multiple errors. The track view that it is loading has no code in it, just a few buttons and labels.

Comment: Duncan, is there anything I need to add to make that code work? I have replaced my code with that and I am getting multiple errors such as undeclared identifier, etc etc.

Comment: The code I posted was a suggestion of a possible approach, not a solution. Absolutely you will have other code to write. You would need to make your track1 view controller a custom subclass of UIViewController, add a `dontAnimateInitialDisplay` property to the class, and then write code to do something with that property.

Comment: If your track1 view controller does not have any custom code and is just a vanilla UIViewController then you are going to need to provide a more complete explanation of what you are seeing. Can you capture a short video of the animations that you are seeing and post them as a GIF, or a link to a Youtube clip or something?

Comment: I have posted it here.. https://imgflip.com/gif/wwqq7 You will see that the back button which is a label sizes up when the view is presented.

Answer (score 1):

Animation can be implemented in track1 view controller which you presented. For example in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear.

Check for `[UIView animateWithDuration:`...

Comment: I still have not got any of the solutions to work, I have attached the gif below to show the problem you will see the back button will resize.

https://imgflip.com/gif/wwqq7

Comment: Better will be if you show code of your "track1" view controller.

Comment: I will add it above.

Comment: It's not enough info please provide also .h file, and maybe you have some UIViev category?